# recycler view not showing from realtime databse

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, data-class

I have a simple recycler view that reads a list from the database, I can see data when I log them to the console, but it doesn't show in the recycler view

**The function below is in the kotlin fragment class for the xml layout containing the recycler view**

```
 override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?,
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val view: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chat_list, container, false)


        view.recyclerView?.setHasFixedSize(true)
        view.recyclerView?.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)




        ref?.addChildEventListener(object : ChildEventListener {
            override fun onChildAdded(snapshot: DataSnapshot, previousChildName: String?) {
                val bal = snapshot.getValue<UserInfo.Uids>()

                if (bal != null) {
                 UserInfo.Uids(bal.email,bal.uid,bal.displayName)         
               }
                Log.d("RecyclerView",  UserInfo.Uids().toString())
                Log.d("RecyclerView", bal.toString())
                adapter = BalAdapter(requireContext(),  ArrayList<UserInfo.Uids>(),  R.layout.users)
                adapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
            }

            override fun onChildChanged(snapshot: DataSnapshot, previousChildName: String?) {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }

                override fun onChildRemoved(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }

            override fun onChildMoved(snapshot: DataSnapshot, previousChildName: String?) {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }

            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
                TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
            }




        })
        adapter = BalAdapter(requireContext(),  ArrayList<UserInfo.Uids>(),  R.layout.users)
        view.recyclerView.adapter = adapter
        adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()

        return  view

    }
```

> `R.layout.fragment_chat_list` is the xml containing the recycler view tag

> `R.layout.users` is the data xml

> `view.recyclerView` is the recycler view tag

> `BalAdapter` is the adapter class, can be provided on request, but I feel the code there is correct

> `UserInfo.Uids` is the data class, contains `name` and `email`

> `adapter` variable was declared before the `override fun onCreateView`

Comment: You are initializing the adapter `adapter = BalAdapter(requireContext(), ArrayList<UserInfo.Uids>(),  R.layout.users)` both inside and outside the `.addChildEventListener`. 
Now since there will be delay in data retreival, the adapter outside `.addChildEventListener` will be executed with an empty ArrayList and since you have not set `view.recyclerView.adapter = adapter` inside `.addChildEventListener` those data will not be considered.

Comment: Where you are passing data to your adapter.
1. You are passing empty array list to adapter.
2. You are creating 2 instance of adapter class.

Comment: Thanks for your response, so please, what should I do?

Comment: @Kishan, how would I pass a populated array?

Comment: I removed one instance of the adapter class, it still didn't work

Comment: Can you add your adapter class code?

Comment: I had it resolved

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66699641/inserting-firebase-snapshot-in-recyclerview-kotlin/66702264#66702264

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66699641/inserting-firebase-snapshot-in-recyclerview-kotlin/66702264#66702264

Comment: @Justin It sounds like an answer ;)