# inserting firebase snapshot in recyclerview kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, data-class

I have a simple recycler view that reads a list from the database, I can see data when I log them to the console, *but it doesn't show in the recycler view*

**The function below is in the kotlin fragment class for the xml layout containing the recycler view**

```
 override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?,
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val view: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chat_list, container, false)


        view.recyclerView?.setHasFixedSize(true)
        view.recyclerView?.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)




        ref?.addChildEventListener(object : ChildEventListener {
            override fun onChildAdded(snapshot: DataSnapshot, previousChildName: String?) {
                val bal = snapshot.getValue<UserInfo.Uids>()

                if (bal != null) {
                 UserInfo.Uids(bal.email,bal.uid,bal.displayName)         
               }
                Log.d("RecyclerView",  UserInfo.Uids().toString())
                Log.d("RecyclerView", bal.toString())
                adapter = BalAdapter(requireContext(),  ArrayList<UserInfo.Uids>(),  R.layout.users)
                adapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
            }

            override fun onChildChanged(snapshot: DataSnapshot, previousChildName: String?) {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }

                override fun onChildRemoved(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }

            override fun onChildMoved(snapshot: DataSnapshot, previousChildName: String?) {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }

            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
                TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
            }




        })
      
        return  view

    }
```

- `R.layout.fragment_chat_list` is the xml containing the recycler view tag
- `R.layout.users` is the data xml
- `view.recyclerView` is the recycler view tag
- `BalAdapter` is the adapter class, can be provided on request, but I feel the code there is correct
- `UserInfo.Uids` is the data class, contains `name` and `email`
- `adapter` variable was declared before the `override fun onCreateView`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't look like you're filling the recyclerview up with any data. The adapter is always initialized with an empty `ArrayList`:

```
                                    /* This is an empty ArrayList */
adapter = BalAdapter(requireContext(),  ArrayList<UserInfo.Uids>(),  R.layout.users)
```

You'll need to add the values you read from firebase into an arraylist, then pass that arraylist into the adapter

For example:

```
//Before any firebase requests:
val balList = ArrayList<UserInfo.Uids>()
adapter = BalAdapter(requireContext(), balList,  R.layout.users)

...

//After you get data from firebase
val bal = snapshot.getValue<UserInfo.Uids>()
balList.add(bal)
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```